# Docker / Windows Container: how to mount a host folder as data volume on Windows 2016

Tags: mount, docker, windows-server, windows-server-2016

**How to mount a volume from Windows host to Windows guest system?**

I am on Windows Server 2016 TP4 using Docker.

Following the documentation on 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon
>   has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker
>   Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows)
>   directory. So, you can mount files or directories on OS X using.
>
> On Windows, mount directories using:
>
> docker run -v /c/Users/[path]:/[container path] ...`

I tried:

```
docker run --name iisdemo2 -it -p 80:80 -v /c/Users/mlin/meinedaten:/meinedaten iis cmd
```

which gives me an error:

```
docker : docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "/c/Users/mlin/meinedaten:/meinedaten": volumeinvalid: Invalid volume specification: 
'/c/Users/mlin/meinedaten:/meinedaten'.
```

I also tried:

```
docker run --name iisdemo2 -it -p 80:80 -v /c/Users/mlin/meinedaten:/c/meinedaten iis cmd
```

Note that the path C:\meinedaten on the guest/container exist already, which is required according to the docker documentation.

The command looks correct to me according to the documentation.

[image]

(Mounting volumes from Mac OS X host to Ubuntu docker container works fine, I am just having problems with Windows.)

***Update***

I also just tried to use Windows Containers natively (via Powershell), not using Docker. I follow the documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_powershell#create-a-shared-folder.

```
Add-ContainerSharedFolder -ContainerName mysql2 -SourcePath C:\Users\mlin\meinedaten -DestinationPath C:\meinedaten
```

But I am getting problems there are as well.

[image]

**Eventually related topics:**

- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12751
- https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/84
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053968/mount-volume-to-host

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On Windows, the paths must be specified using Windows-style semantics. **You should not use a leading slash in front of the path.**

```
docker run -v c:\Users\[path]:c:\[containerPath]
```

Comment: This does not work if you created the folders with a copy or add command.

Comment: the host dir can be also relative "./" and guest internal os might be linux type of os thus regular linux path "/a/b/c/" like , in docker compose this way ` volumes:
                - ./:/var/www/html`

Answer (score 7):

Windows 10 Anniversary Update and Windows Server 2016 RTM.

Add a volume:

```
docker run -d -v my-named-volume:C:\MyNamedVolume testimage:latest
```

Mount a host directory:

```
docker run -d -v C:\Temp\123:C:\My\Shared\Dir testimage:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the docker CLI from a Mac machine and trying to run Windows containers? If so, I'm assuming you've got a `DOCKER_HOST` env var set and your daemon is running on a Windows machine (since you can't run Windows containers on any OS other than Windows).

If that's the case, then the directory you're trying to mount into the container must be a directory on the docker host, not the machine that happens to be running the docker CLI. Therefore you can use the Windows format on both sides of the colon. If you're trying to mount a directory that exists on your Mac, I haven't figured that part out yet, but will need to myself :)

Comment: > Are you running the docker CLI from a Mac machine and trying to run Windows containers? 

--> No, all Windows. I already found the solution as marked. Note it's 4 years ago, I don't work with Windows Containers anymore these days.