# How to access Windows shared network drive from Windows Docker Container

Tags: windows, mount, docker, docker-for-windows

I need to access my network shared drive D: from my Windows container.
Using Docker Desktop 2.1.0.5 with Windows containers and Windows 10 Pro 1903.

I tried using:

```
docker run --rm -it mydocker/image -v D::C:\D --name myimage
```

and I get this error:

```
 The system cannot find the file specified
```

It tried with the IP address too:

```
docker run --rm -it mydocker/image -v \\ip\data:C:\D --name myimage
```

but I still get the same error.

I tried with Docker Desktop 2.2.0.0 but the error was the same and I rolled back because of this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5567) (just to be sure).

Related question [docker-windows-container-how-to-mount-a-host-folder-as-data-volume-on-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1051520/docker-windows-container-how-to-mount-a-host-folder-as-data-volume-on-windows/1131748#1131748?newreg=e4340be72f2c4ec78b649b9cae862775).

**Edit:**
The image name has to be the last argument, it seems. No I have another error:

```
docker run --rm -it -v \\ip\data:C:\D --name myimage mydocker/image

docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '\\ip\data:C:\D'
```

Comment: Any luck finding the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you used the `net use` command within the container AFTER it has already started.  I started the container with a gMSA and CredentialSpec, but I don't know if it is a requirement.

Within the container I executed `net use D: \\ipaddress\c$` and it prompted me for my credentials:
[image]

The command was successful, now I executed `net use` again so I can see the list of network drives:
[image]

And now I can change drives and list the contents just fine:
[image]